# A fast factorization method for Mersenne numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Given a prime number $p$ and a Mersenne number $M=2^p-1$:

1. Is it true for every prime factor $q$ of $M$ that $q\equiv1\pmod{p}$?

   For example, $p=29$ and $M=536870911=233\cdot1103\cdot2089$:

   - $ 233=29\cdot 8+1$
   - $1103=29\cdot38+1$
   - $2089=29\cdot72+1$
2. If yes, then is there a method which exploits this fact in order to factorize $M$ (or decide it is prime), which is faster than the fastest methods in use for numbers in general?

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/LukeMirror/lit/lit_027s.htm

Comment: For 1: Yes, $p$ is the order of $2 \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\ast}$ so $p \mid |\mathbb{F}_q^{\ast}| = q-1$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728447/efficient-algorithm-for-factorizing-mersenne-numbers/

Answer (score 3):

In general, every divisor of $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime is $\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Also, if memory serves correctly, then it was previously conjectured **only** for primes, until counter-exampled with $2^{341}-1$ (where $341$ is not a prime).

Comment: $\frac{15**7 - 1}{14} = 12204241$. 12204241 factors to 7 and 1743463. $1743463 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, but 7 is obviously not.

Answer (score 2):

1. $q|(2^p-1)\Rightarrow 2^p\equiv 1\pmod q$. Therefore, the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_q^*$ divides $p$ and, since $p$ is prime and $2\neq 1$, it's exactly $p$. By Lagrange's theorem, $p|(q-1)$, that is, $q\equiv 1\pmod p$.
2. I don't know about the *fastest* methods, but the top ten prime numbers are Mersenne numbers...

**Remark**: You can use weaker theorems than Lagrange's. Little Fermat's theorem, for example.

Comment: Just a minor quibble: The fact that all the top primes are Mersenne numbers has nothing to do with factorization algorithms. It has to do with the existence of a very efficient primality test for Mersennes: the Lucas-Lehmer test.